# PySpark: Data is too large to store in a single machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am having the problem that my data is too large to store in a single machine in the cluster for loading and processing by Pyspark later. I'm new to PySpark so I wonder if there is any solution for my case?

I am thinking about two solution:

- My data consists of some small subsets and these small subsets are small enough to store on a machine. So can I save different pieces of data in different machines and then load and process?
- If I set up HDFS to store data, can this HDFS use storage from many different machines instead of just from a single machine?

I prefer the first way, if possible can you please give me sample code to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far please attach your code), what is the error and how big is your data ? The whole idea of using pyspark is that you can partition your data so it is processed in parallel in multiple machines. When you read the data using pyspark,, mention the partitions. You can specify the number of partitions or even partition by a certain column. Trying to process a huge file on 1 machine is just going to be really slow. Here is a good article to refer to https://medium.com/datalex/on-spark-performance-and-partitioning-strategies-72992bbbf150